# How to convert a string to a numeric in autohotkey?

Tags: string, format, converters, numeric, autohotkey

`FormatTime, CurrentMinute , , m` assigns the current minute to variable `%CurrentMinute%`, and its value is a string, not a numeric. I wanna do some calculations on the value of `%CurrentMinute%`, so how could I convert it to numeric?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AutoHotkey automatically converts numbers and strings as needed.

```
FormatTime, CurrentMinute,, m
NextMinute := CurrentMinute + 1
```

Comment: Thank you, `CurrentMinute:= CurrentMinute + 0` solved the problem!