# Autohotkey: Send 5 digit hex unicode chars

Tags: windows, unicode, scripting, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I have been trying to find a way to remap my keyboard and send 5-digit hex unicode chars, the method described here: [ahk Send](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) only supports 4-digit hex codes {U+nnnn}, I know that in the past, autohotkey didnt support unicode natively so it was needed some functions in order to do that, maybe thats the solution for me.

Example:

```
#If GetKeyState("CapsLock","T")
+u::Send {U+1D4B0}
```

The results from that is 풰 instead of , and the code for 풰 is {U+D4B0}, meaning AHK is reading only the last 4 digits. How can I fix it even if I need to make new functions to achieve that?

Thanks

-Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode values larger than 0xFFFF must be encoded as two surrogate pairs:

```
+u:: SendInput ,{U+D835}{U+DCB0}
```

Here is the algorithm to convert a Unicode *code point* that is in range 0x10000 to 0x10FFFF, to surrogate pairs, paraphrased from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF):

First subtract 0x10000 from the *code point*, to get a *number* in range 0xFFFFF.

Then right shift the *number* by 10 bits and add 0xD800 to it to get the *high surrogate*.

Take the lowest ten bits of the *number* and add 0xDC00 to it to get the *low surrogate*

Comment: Thanks! This one works, now I need to learn about surrogate pairs, could you show me where I can learn more about that? Or even a table with all the codes would be very helpful.

Comment: Wow. I spent HOURS trying to figure this out over the course of a few months. Tried a lot of clever things. Then I realized the problem was only with 5 digit unicode points, googled it, and found this answer. And it works great!

Answer (score 0):

I took 2501's solution from above and turned it into working a working ahk script. I have been searching on and off for this solution for months!

```
+u:: FUNC_SEND_UNICODE( 0x1D4B0 )

FUNC_SEND_UNICODE(func_args)
{

    /*
    ;commented out proof of concept code:
    str := ""
    u1  := Chr( 0xD835 )
    u2  := Chr( 0xDCB0 )
    str := u1 . u2

    bk := clipboard
    clipboard := str
    send, ^v

    sleep,200
    clipboard := bk
    */

    ;bk == "clipboard [B]ac[K]up
    bk := clipboard


    ;chunk of data that needs to be cut into
    ;two chunks.
    ful := func_args + 0


    /*  commented out testing code, using original
        sample input of stack overflow post
    ;msgbox,ful:[%ful%]
    ;for testing. Expecting input to be equal to
    ;the value in the post.
    if(ful != 0x1D4B0 ){
        msgbox,"[WHATTHEHECK]"
    }
    */


    ;Subtract 0x10000 from ful, gets number 
    ;in range(rng) 0x0 to 0xFFFFFF inclusive
    rng := ful - 0x10000
    if(rng > 0xFFFFF)
    {
        msgBox,[Step1 Resulted In Out Of Range]
    }

    ;Do shifting and masking, then check to make
    ;sure the value is in the expected range:
    big_shif := (rng >>   10)
    lit_mask := (rng & 0x3FF)
    if(big_shif > 0x3FF)
    {
        msgBox,[MATH_ERROR:big_shif]
    }
    if(lit_mask > 0x3FF)
    {
        msgBox,[MATH_ERROR:lit_mask]
    }

    big := big_shif + 0xD800
    lit := lit_mask + 0xDC00
    if(big < 0xD800 || big >= 0xDBFF){
        msgBox, [HIGH_SURROGATE_OUT_OF_BOUNDS]
    }
    if(lit < 0xDC00 || lit >= 0xDFFF){
        msgBox, [LOW_SURROGATE_OUT_OF_BOUNDS]
    }

    ;Convert code points to actual characters:
    u1 := Chr( big )
    u2 := Chr( lit )

    ;concatentate those two characters to
    ;create our final surrogate output:
    str := u1 . u2

    ;set it equal to clipboard, and send
    ;the clipboard. This is a hack.
    ;send,%str% works fine in google chrome,
    ;but fails in notepad++ for some reason.
    ;tried appending EOF, STX, ETX control codes
    ;along with output, but to no effect.
    clipboard := str
    send, ^v

    ;Must sleep before restoring clipboard,
    ;otherwise, the clipboard will get
    ;overwritten before ctrl+v has the chance
    ;to output the character. You'll end up just
    ;pasting whatever was originally on the
    ;clipboard.
    sleep,200
    clipboard := bk

    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of [2501's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36568246/2617068).

1. Listens for `;u`
2. Followed by an ending character (e.g. `;` or <kbd>Return</kbd>)
3. Waits for a sequence of keypresses like <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>
4. Input ends when terminated by a `;`
5. Sends the desired Unicode character directly if below 65536, calculates surrogate pairs otherwise
6. Inserts the desired Unicode character

```
:?:`;u::
    Input, keys, , `;
    if (StrLen(keys) < 5)
        Send {U+%keys%}
    else {
        keys := "0x" + keys
        num := keys - 0x10000
        w1 := Format("{:x}", (num >> 10) + 0xD800)
        w2 := Format("{:x}", (num & 1023) + 0xDC00)
        Send {U+%w1%}{U+%w2%}
    }
    return
```

For reference:

- [Hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)
- [Input](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm)
- [StrLen](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringLen.htm)
- [Casting string to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106275/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-numeric-in-autohotkey)
- [Format](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Format.htm)
- [Bitwise operations](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=1744)
- [Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)

Answer (score -1):

From somewhere on the internet: `sendunicodechar(0x1D4B0)`

```
SendUnicodeChar(charCode)
{
    VarSetCapacity(ki, 28 * 2, 0)
    EncodeInteger(&ki + 0, 1)
    EncodeInteger(&ki + 6, charCode)
    EncodeInteger(&ki + 8, 4)
    EncodeInteger(&ki +28, 1)
    EncodeInteger(&ki +34, charCode)
    EncodeInteger(&ki +36, 4|2)

    DllCall("SendInput", "UInt", 2, "UInt", &ki, "Int", 28)
}

EncodeInteger(ref, val)
{
    DllCall("ntdll\RtlFillMemoryUlong", "Uint", ref, "Uint", 4, "Uint", val)
}
```

edit. probably got downvoted bc of missing source. I simply dont know where I got it from anymore. But when I used it a few years ago, it worked flawlessly.

Comment: I found these functions before and they dont seem to work even for 4 digit hex codes, I tested it back then and just now and it still didnt work for me. Maybe they worked in a older version of AHK.

Comment: are you using win10? in win7 64bit, it did it for me.

Comment: Yes, Win10 64, ahk version: 1.1.22.09